# Create 301 on urls with params

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I have a list of urls like this: `mydomain.com/?page_id=40` and need to redirect them all to `mydomain.com/sefurl`

I have tried this in the `.htaccess` file, but it did not do it.

```
Redirect 301 /?page_id=40 http://mydomain.com/sefurl
```

I have 20-30 urls that need rewrite

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?page_id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /sefurl? [R=301,L]
```

The above should redirect `mydomain.com/?page_id=33` to `mydomain.com/sefurl`

Comment: Thanks, But what to do if I have more then one url going to different sef urls?

Comment: That would depend on what the end sef url is to look like. With the url you have given you could do something like `mydomain.com/page/40`

Comment: /?page_id=11 should 301 to /pasienthistorier

Can i do 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?page_id=11(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /pasienthistorier [R=301,L]